# ExtJs 6.0 - Ext.dom.Element.query() - multiple values in attribute - correct selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, css-selectors

My [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13ht) looks like this:

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
   var my_panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        html: "<img id='1' foo='4 6 8' src='http://i342.photobucket.com/albums/o416/TaySensei/avatar_me_in_anime_1_by_maria345.jpg'/>" + 
              "<img id='2' foo='5 7 9 10' src='http://i621.photobucket.com/albums/tt296/Kruh11/KruhPic50x50LQ.jpg'/>" +
              "<img id='3' foo='6 4' src='http://i744.photobucket.com/albums/xx84/no_photos_here/communitytile-1.jpg'/>"
    });
    var my_viewport =  Ext.create("Ext.container.Viewport",{
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [my_panel],
        renderTo : Ext.getBody()
    });
    var queried_imgs = my_panel.body.query("img[foo='4']");


    Ext.toast('queried_imgs = ' + queried_imgs);
  }
});
```

**My question is:**
In line 15 I am trying to use the `Ext.dom.Element.query(selector)`-method to query for `img` tags containing the value `4` in their `foo` attribute.

Yet `queried_imgs` is empty.

---

***What is the correct CSS-selector to retrieve the `img` tags containing `4` in their `foo` attribute?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the various attribute selectors which select an element based on their attribute and value. You can use whichever suits your case the best. You can find more details about the various available CSS attribute selectors in the [W3C Selectors Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

CSS Selector for `img` tag which has a `foo` attribute whose value contains 4 - `img[foo*='4']`

```css
img[foo*='4']{
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='4 5' /> <!-- will select this -->
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='41' />  <!-- and this -->
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='14' />  <!-- and this -->
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='4' />   <!-- and this -->
```

**Note:** I believe that you are looking only for the above selector.

---

CSS Selector for `img` tag which has a `foo` attribute whose value starts with 4 - 
`img[foo^='4']`

```css
img[foo^='4']{
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='4 5' /> <!-- will select only this -->
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='41' />  <!-- and this -->
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='14' />
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='4' />   <!-- and this -->
```

CSS selector for `img` tag which has a `foo` attribute whose value is exactly 4 - `img[foo='4']`

```css
img[foo='4']{
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='4 5' />
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='41' />
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='14' />
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='4' />   <!-- will select only this -->
```

---

CSS selector for `img` tag which has a `foo` attribute which has a list of space separated values one among which is exactly 4 - `img[foo~='4']`

```css
img[foo~='4']{
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='4 5' />   <!-- this will select this -->
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='41 21' />
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='14 34' />
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='4' />     <!-- and this -->
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4' foo='159 4' /> <!-- and this -->
```

**Note:** The `~=` selector would select elements `#1` and `#3` in your code. But it is not exactly select an element whose foo attribute **contains** 4.

Comment: I think you forgot `~=` which is used to search for one class in a class list, so `[foo~=4]` would find `4 5` but not `45`.

Comment: Actually i was looking for `img[foo~='4']`